# Use of parentheses in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am getting this error:

```
<interactive>:145:29:
    Could not deduce (Integral ([a0] -> Int))
      arising from a use of ‘fromIntegral’
    from the context (Num ([a] -> a), Fractional a)
      bound by the inferred type of
               meanList :: (Num ([a] -> a), Fractional a) => [a] -> a
      at <interactive>:145:5-50
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    In the second argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘(fromIntegral length x)’
    In the expression: (sum x) / (fromIntegral length x)
    In an equation for ‘meanList’:
        meanList x = (sum x) / (fromIntegral length x)
```

Above error is generated by:

```
meanList x = (sum x) / (fromIntegral length x)
```

However, when updating this to:

```
let meanList x = sum x / fromIntegral (length x)
```

Then all is well.

**How do parentheses work in Haskell?**

Comment: This isn't a problem with parentheses, but function application.

Comment: When in doubt, add a `$`: `fromIntegral $ length x` is the same as `fromIntegral (length x)`, but you don't need to track where the closing parenthesis must be.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Function application is left associative. In other words,

```
fromIntegral length x = (fromIntegral length) x
```

Hence the error `Could not deduce (Integral ([a0] -> Int))` because the type of length does indeed not have an instance of `Integral`.

Comment: @Yuck You can catch me on freenode as srhb as I don't think this is a relevant venue for such a conversation. Also: Everything. :)

Comment: @Yuck what a strange question :o